# Compare 2 sentences and get index of the different word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a `contenteditable` div

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    hey @twitter is #
</div>
```

As soon as user types `#`, I will collect its html content as `$('#editableDiv').html()`
html content collected (1): `<b>hey</b> <span style="color:blue">@twitter</span> #`

When user types next immediate space, I'll collect its html content again
html content collected (2): `<b>hey</b> <span style="color:blue">@twitter</span> #awesome`

And now, would like to calculate the differences between (1) and (2) and get the index of different words.
As per this, `awesome` is the only word different in (1) and (2) and so its starting index must be 53 and ending index must be 60.

How can I get this done.

**Edit**

Here is the function which I call when user types `#` or `space bar`

```
getCaretPosition : function(){
            var element = this.$el[0];
            var caretOffset = 0;
           if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
                var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
                preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
                preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
                caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
                var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
                preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
                preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
                caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
            }
            return caretOffset;
        }
```

Comment: While I type this out, you need to post your javascript for us to see what you've already tried

Comment: @deryc. I edited my question. I have only one function which returns index of the character (`#` or `space bar`) from beginning of the `editableDiv`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic solution:

```
$('#editableDiv').on('keyup', function (event) {

    var innerHTML = $(this).html();
        matches = {},
        startIndex = 0;

    if (event.which === 32) {
        innerHTML.match(/#[^ ]+/g).forEach(function (match) {
            startIndex = innerHTML.indexOf(match, startIndex);
            matches[match] = startIndex;
        });
        console.log(matches);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4PLJa/5/

Comment: Perfect answer. Any chances of extending this functionality to calculate index only for required `#` and its word. 'Coz sentence may have n number of `#` and words attached but would to apply this functionality only for a particular `#` and its word.

Comment: Thanks @micnic, it works but how to get matched word index in sentence

Comment: @Metri, if you really need them see the updated answer

Comment: There is something wrong with the output. Please see the ss [here](http://snag.gy/jPHiJ.jpg) . Expected output was 17 but it has returned 21. Thanks

Comment: @Metri, you may have missed some whitespace there, try to escape the html from tags and special encoding like &nbsp;

Answer (score 1):

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rGN35/)

```
var before = "",
    after = "",
    diffIndex;
$('#editableDiv').on({
    focus: function () {
        before = $(this).text();
    },
    blur: function () {
        after = $(this).text().substring(before.length, $(this).text().length);
        diffIndex = before.length;
        console.log(before);
        console.log(after);
        console.log(diffIndex);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This will fail if user types `#awesome` anywhere at the except end of the sentence. Thanks

Comment: Your specific setup stated that you were only calling this before/after diff check at the moment the user typed `#`.  Which means everything before the `#awesome` would go into the `before` and the text following would be placed into `after`.  If I mis-interpreted your goals I apologize